# JAX-RS: Custom TypeConverter for resteasy-jettison

Tags: jax-rs, jboss7.x, resteasy, jettison

Is there any way to provide Custom TypeConverter in resteasy-jettison? By default jettison parse String value into int if it contains only numbers... I need to change it.

With clean jettison, there is possibility to write own implementation of TypeConverter (described in [jettison user's guide](http://jettison.codehaus.org/User%27s+Guide#UsersGuide-Typeconversion)... But I have no Idea where could I update jettison configuration with such class.

Answer (score 0):

Set the system property to below class.

System.setProperty("jettison.mapped.typeconverter.class", "org.codehaus.jettison.mapped.SimpleConverter");

So jettison have simple converter which always output the values as strings.